# How to write a segment that is not two other segments

Tags: request, segments, getsegment

How can I write:

- is segment 3, and is not itemA and is not itemB?
- both itemA and itemB are segment 3 as well.

`{% if craft.app.request.getSegment(3) and craft.request.getSegment(3) !== 'itemA' and craft.request.getSegment(3) !== 'itemB' %}`

To clarify, I want to target a category that is segment 3, but I want to omit two other categories that are on the same segment(level):

- Topics Category

  - Subcategory
  - Subcategory

    - itemA(omit)
    - itemB(omit)
    - itemC(yes)
    - itemD(yes)

In code, I want to achieve this:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) == 'Subcategory' %}
   // do something
{% elseif craft.app.request.getSegment(3) and craft.request.getSegment(3) !== 'itemA' and craft.request.getSegment(3) !== 'itemB' %}
   // do other stuff
{% else %}
   // do a generic thing
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm not following... how can segment 3 be both not itemA and not itemB as well as be in segment 3?

Comment: @Brad I think he wants to test if segment 3 is actually set (not empty) but it should not be 'itemA' and not 'itemB' so the condition should be true if the segment is 'itemC'. His explanation is a little bit confusing, I suppose he just wants to tell us that the segment could be 'itemA' or B but the condition should not become true then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally try to avoid inlining too many conditionals because I feel like it leaves room for logical loopholes. I also think using variables for segments keeps things easier to read.

```
{% set seg2 = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set seg3 = craft.request.getSegment(3) %}
```

So maybe something like this? The keyword `in` is Twig's way of checking `in_array()`

```
{% set badItems = ['itemA', 'itemB'] %}

{% if seg2 == 'Subcategory' %}
    // do top priority thing
{% elseif seg3 != '' and seg3 not in badItems %}
    // do secondary thing
{% else %}
    // do overall default thing
{% endif %}
```

---

However, if you know the finite list of acceptable items beforehand, I think this is more concise.  Since segment 3 could be blank if it's not there, maybe try checking if it *is* something instead of if it's *not* something.

```
{% set goodItems = ['itemC', 'itemD'] %}

{% if seg2 == 'Subcategory' %}
    // do top priority thing
{% elseif seg3 in goodItems %}
    // do secondary thing
{% else %}
    // do overall default thing
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I like everything about this. The thought process and structured approach.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I went years overlooking that `in` keyword in Twig, but it's so helpful since so much of programming deals with arrays.